# How to push to the bare repository for the first time (in Git)?

Tags: git, git-bare

I have created a bare repository for Git using the following command (on my server):

```
mkdir socialclub.git
cd socialclub.git
git --bare init
```

Then on my local machine, I used the git init in a non-empty directory using the following command:

```
git init
```

Then I added `.gitignore` to ignore the files I don't want. Then I used `git add` to add the files I want, after that I used `git commit`. At this point, when I use `git status` I get the following:

```
ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

At this point, I want to push my initial code to the bare repo. I tried doing the following:

1. I added the remote (called it `upstream`), the `git remote -v` returns the following:

   ```
   ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git remote -v
   upstream    codesheidaei@code.sheidaei.com:/repo/socialclub.git (fetch)
   upstream    codesheidaei@code.sheidaei.com:/repo/socialclub.git (push)
   ```
2. As the next step I'm trying is to push the changes to the repo as follow:

   ```
   ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git push --set-upstream upstream master
   codesheidaei@code.sheidaei.com's password: 
   fatal: '/repo/socialclub.git' does not appear to be a git repository
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   ```

Any idea what should I do differently?

Comment: Just try: ```git push origin master```

Comment: Or you can try adding a readme file and doing `git add .` `git commit -m"initial commit"` and then `git push origin master`

Comment: Everything looks good, except one question: are we to assume you are in the root folder `/repo` when you ran `mkdir socialclub.git` on the server?

Comment: Also, I don't think it matters, but try using the option *after* the command. So `git --bare init` should be `git init --bare`

Comment: Is this repo at the given absolute path `/repo/socialclub.git` on the remote machine?

Comment: If `repo` is just in the home directory of user `shahinsheidaei` on the remote machine, then use a relative path: `shahinsheidaei@code.sheidaei.com:repo/socialclub.git`.

Comment: If you do `ssh shahinshaedaei@code.sheidaei.com ls -l /repo/socialclub.git`, what happens? How about `ls repo/socialclub.git`?

Comment: @prabodhprakash I tried but got the same result: 

ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git add .
ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git commit -m"initial commit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$ git push upstream  master
codesheidaei@code.sheidaei.com's password: 
fatal: '/repo/socialclub.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ShahinX:SocialClub shahinsheidaei$

Comment: @JeffPuckettII yes for the first question and I tried, it didn't help.

Comment: @Kaz I tried with the relative path, it didn't work when I wanted to push master.

Comment: @Kaz thanks this was the key! when I did ssh shahinshaedaei@code.sheidaei.com ls -l /repo/socialclub.git I found out what the problem was. I should have defined the remote as git remote set-url upstream codesheidaei@code.sheidaei.com:code.sheidaei.com/repo/socialclub.git
the repo was not the root folder, which I assumed to be!